# C++ Linker error when trying to use variable from another class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, linker-errors, extern

I am very new to c++ and this error has been doing my head in. Basically I have a class called **PvSimpleUISampleDlg** which is a GUI that displays and interfaces a FLIR thermal camera. In the DoDataExchange method I have a line that links IDC_IP_EDIT with mIPEdit which is used elsewhere in the class.

```
//PvSimpleUISampleDlg.cpp
void PvSimpleUISampleDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_IP_EDIT, mIPEdit);
}
```

I made a new dialog box class called **SettingsDlg** that opens when I click a button in the **PvSimpleUISampleDlg** class and I want to use the same mIPEdit variable in that dialog box so the data is the same in each part of the GUI. So I went into the **PvSimpleUISampleDlg.h** file and put extern in front of the mIPEdit deceleration so that the other class can see it.

```
//PvSimpleUISampleDlg.h
extern CEdit mIPEdit;
```

Now in the **SettingsDlg.cpp** file I put the same line in its own DoDataExchange method and sure enough it recognized the mIPEdit variable.

```
//SettingsDlg.cpp
void SettingsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_IP_EDIT, mIPEdit);
}
```

However when I now build the solution I get an error

```
1>PvSimpleUISampleDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CEdit mIPEdit" (?mIPEdit@@3VCEdit@@A)
1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CEdit mIPEdit" (?mIPEdit@@3VCEdit@@A)
1>D:\FLIR Project\FLIR Project\PvSimpleUISample\Debug\PvSimpleUISample_Dbg.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I have included the **PvSimpleUISampleDlg.h** file in both the **SettingsDlg.cpp** and **SettingsDlg.h** files and all I have done is copy one line. I have read many questions asking similar things but I still don't understand because the answers were along the lines of "You need to link it to both projects" or "you need to include the libraries in the project" I have added both **SettingsDlg** files to the project and I am only using one project. All the appropriate libraries should be linked to the project because the solution was building fine, the error only appears as soon as I add that line. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you declare that `mIPEdit` variable ?

Comment: _I want to use the same mIPEdit variable in that dialog box so the data is the same in each part of the GUI._ - you don't need to re-use the variable to accomplish this.  In fact, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Trying to learn C++, and MFC, and the Windows API all at the same time is almost impossible to end successfully (and your question history indicates little progress). C++ is challenging enough, all by itself. Either learn C++ (through command line based applications), or go with C (and a tiny bit of C++) and the Windows API, if you want to have a GUI. Do not use MFC, unless you are proficient in C++ or the Windows API (ideally both).

Comment: The DDX_Control statement in SettigsDlg is only valid for a control that is part of the dialog. From what you have said I do not think that dialog has the IDC_IP_EDIT control.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand,

```
 extern CEdit mIPEdit;
```

That is a declaration, not a definition.
You still have to have its definition in some .cpp file somewhere. That .cpp file had to be compiled and linked against the object files of your two .cpp files that use that declaration. The corresponding definition in some .cpp looks like this:

```
CEdit mIPEdit;
```

Comment: So originally in the .h file I had `CEdit mIPEdit` then when I added the extern I had to move it outside the class. Are you saying that I need both? Because I tried to have both `CEdit mIPEdit` and `extern CEdit mIPEdit` and it still gave the error

Comment: Use `CEdit mIPEdit` in global scope is making this variable static storage and global visibility. Include the header that contains this line in two .cpp files will show you the error of "multiple definitions" I think, because each .cpp that includes it will produce a definition in its object file. Change that to `extern` won't work either, since the compiler accept "ok its extern so I will resolve at link time", but there needs to be only one definition in one .cpp file that compiles out the needed symbol. You could try use "extern" in the header, then in one cpp use non-extern.